# How to programmatically rename XYZUpperCamelCase files to xyzLowerCamelCase?

Tags: bash, file-rename

I have a great number of files that need `svn mv`'d, and I'd rather not do it all by hand.

Each file name follows the format `XYZSomething.txt` or `SomethingElse.txt`, and should be renamed to `xyzSomething.txt` and `somethingElse.txt`, respectively.

If I didn't need to deal with the abbreviation prefix, I could just use something like

```
for f in *; do svn mv $f ${f,}; done
```

which lowercases just the first character in the filename. As it stands, this gets me 90% of the way, so it wouldn't be too painful to finish it by hand; but I would still like to know how to cover the prefix for future knowledge.

So tell me, great Bash wizards of StackOverflow, what's the best way to rename these files?

Comment: So the rule is: if the filename starts with exactly one uppercase letter, then lowercase that letter, but if it starts with a sequence of *n* uppercase letters (*n* > 1), then lowercase only the first *n*-minus-1 of them?

Comment: Yes. Another way to think of it could be to lowercase the first letter, and any following it that are themselves followed by an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

So you can do this:

```
$ echo ThisIsAFileName | sed 's/^\([A-Z]*\)\(.*\)/\L\1\E\2/'
thisIsAFileName
```

or:

```
for f in *; do svn mv $f `echo $f | sed 's/^\([A-Z]*\)\(.*\)/\L\1\E\2/'`; done
```

The \L in sed will make the following letters lowercase up until \E

If it's just the first letter, then you can do:

```
$ echo ThisIsAFileName | sed 's/.*/\l&/'
thisIsAFileName
```

\l will just turn the next letter lower case

However, XYZFileName would get renamed to xyzfileName, just because the distinction between XYZ and F is not there...

Hope this helps

Comment: Re XYZFileName -> xyzfileName, is easy to fix via 's/^\([A-Z]*\)\([A-Z]\)\(.*\)/\L\1\E\2\3/' [haven't tested but I expect it produces FileName -> FileName which isn't wanted]

Answer (score 0):

That will do the trick with both the two examples :

```
  $ sed -r 's@^([a-Z]+)([A-Z].*)@\L\1\E\2@' <<< XYZSomething
  xyzSomething

  $ sed -r 's@^([a-Z]+)([A-Z].*)@\L\1\E\2@' <<< SomethingElse
  somethingElse
```

Comment: I get `sed: 1: "s@^([a-Z]+)([A-Z].*)@\L ...": RE error: invalid character range` when I try it.

Comment: Did you type exactly the same command like me ? I have `GNU sed version 4.2.1`

Comment: @AustinHyde: Try changing `[a-Z]` to `[a-zA-Z]`. @sputnick: I don't think the `.*` and the `g` are useful here.

Comment: After changing `[a-Z]`, the XYZSomething sample gives me `LXYZESomething`

Comment: I provide you a [tag:sed] version, what is yours and wich distro do you use ?